# Proxy pass websocket connections to another port

Tags: apache, nginx

So I have Openfire installed and the admin backoffice is running on port 9090. I am trying to connect with Strophe via websocket on port 7070 so I did this in Nginx:

```
server {
        server_name example.com;
        root /var/www/html;

        location /ws/server {
            proxy_pass http://openfire:7070/ws/server;
            # this magic is needed for WebSocket
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }

        location / {
           proxy_redirect    off;
           proxy_set_header  Host               $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_pass http://openfire:9090/;
        }

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
                allow all;
                root /var/www/html;
        }
}
```

It works fine. But unfortunately I have to use Apache Http Server instead of Nginx so now I need to rewrite this code for Apache Http server.
Here's my attempt:

```
  GNU nano 5.4                               openfire-https-vhost.conf                                         
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443 _default_:443>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias *
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/server.key"
  # BEGIN: Configuration for letsencrypt
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/letsencrypt/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
  # END: Configuration for letsencrypt
  # BEGIN: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy without Location
  <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyPass /.well-known !
    ProxyPass /ws/server !
  </IfModule>
  # END: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy without Location

  <Location />
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:9090/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:9090/
  </Location>

  <Location /ws/server>
    RewriteEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://127.0.0.1:7070/ws/server$1 [P,L]
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1/ws/server
    ProxyPassReverse /
  </Location>

  # BEGIN: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy within Location
  <Location /.well-known>
    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
      ProxyPass !
    </IfModule>
  </Location>
  # END: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy within Location
</VirtualHost>
```

But now when I try to connect via Postman I get this error on the server;

```
2023.11.04 17:49:18 WARN  [Jetty-QTP-BOSH-70]: org.jivesoftware.openfire.websocket.OpenfireWebSocketServlet - Failed to create websocket for 127.0.0.1:57752 make a request at /server/127.0.0.1/ws/server
```

Can anyone please help me to rewrite the nginx to apache code.